# Complex class and pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I try to understand to many complex as class, as in this code example :

```
class System
{
    int info;

    public:
      System *parent;
      System() {info = 0; parent=0;}
};

class Window
{
    public:
      Window();
};

class SoftWindow : public Window
{
     protected:
       System *systemWindow;
       Window *parent;

     public:
       Softwindow();
};
```

In `System *parent` I would like to understand what it does mean this pointer object in the same class `System`? Same here in the class `Softwindow` for `System *systewindow` ? What it does mean two pointer `System` in separation from class ? Can I assign with the pointer `System *systemWindow` to pointer `System *parent` even from two different class ?

Thanks

Comment: `System parent*;` is just malformed code.

Comment: Sorry for bad typo, I mean of course System *parent; I will fix to the typo, thank you.

Comment: You have listed class definitions. There are no actual objects instantiated . Might help if you tell us what you are are trying to do and some minimal code as an example. A ptr to an object can be assigned to a ptr to the same type object if both are visible even if declared in different classes.